# How to install python package as if the computer were brand new?

Tags: python

I would like to test python package installation for a user with a clean Windows and Python installation.

This means that any python packages that are installed which need compilation should throw errors.

How can I test for this? Do I need a full virtual machine? Simply installing into a clean virtual environment doesn't give the same experience.

Comment: While it's not a full-blown machine/environment, maybe a container is a reasonable middleground?

Comment: I hadn't thought of that at all. I'll have to see if I have access to Docker. We do have VMWare, although I also need to get a Windows image...

Answer (score 1):

That is a use case of pyenv and pipenv.

**Pyenv** creates multiple separate python interpreter installs.

- https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv (Posix)
- https://github.com/pyenv-win/pyenv-win (Windows port)

**Pipenv** creates a per app means to specify which interpreter (pyenv) and which packages at what version are used.

- https://github.com/pypa/pipenv

The combination, together with a test environment like pytest can be used to automate testing across many configurations.

Another way is docker, but IMO for this use case that just complicates things.

Comment: That does sound promising. As well as mimicking user experiences, could this also be used to compile specific versions of packages that have c extensions?

Comment: Except that pyenv doesn't do Windows. There is a Windows port pyenv-win

Comment: Python extensions that are complied are often tricky to install in Windows. One way to get round windows vs linux is to use WSL2 together with an XServer like MobaXterm